# Reducing the number of calls to _m_default_append

Tags: c++, optimization, vector

I'm currently trying to make a C++ project go faster. Profiling (using Apple Instruments and Callgrind) made an interesting point:

- On macOS, the function `std::vector::__append` (that creates new default objects and puts them at the end of the vector) represents the majority of the execution time
- On Ubuntu (VM), the function `std::vector::_M_default_append` (which essentially does the same thing) is the culprit. In this case, it currently represents 671,000,000 samples (while my most expensive function is ~14,000).

For obvious reasons, I'd like to reduce the time I spend in these `append` functions, as they are really costly. How can I achieve that? What really surprises me is that I thought I would not have these issues arising since all my vectors are constructed and either `resize()`'d or `reserve()`'d appropriately...

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: For context you'll need to show how you're exercising the vector, in particular which insertion method you're using and what you're inserting. How does performance compare to some baseline like a `new[]` array of same?

Comment: Try reserving enough space in the vector 1st see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve  This will save the copies when the vector needs to expand.

Comment: Double-check that `append` is not causing the vector to resize, and make sure that copying/constructing an element is not overly expensive. Can you refine the profiling to see what part of `append` consumes the time?

Comment: @tadman I am using `vector::emplace_back`. I haven't tested with an array, I actually wanted to avoid using one (but I will probably have to try it out to see how it plays out).

Comment: @RichardCritten I evoked something in the last paragraph of my question, how is that different from mine?

Comment: @JaMiT I think the `append` functions is what causes the vector to resize (or, more precisely, the result of the vector having to resize, according to [the source code](https://code.woboq.org/gcc/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/vector.tcc.html#_ZNSt6vector17_M_default_appendEm). What I am not sure about is why it is called, since as I said, I `reserve` or `resize` at vector construction time so the size should be sufficient. That said, there definitely is an issue as Instruments shows the CPU is inactive during long times after which memory usage jumps (so prob. memory being reallocated)

Comment: @ThomasKowalski Hmm... source code... let's see... More accurately, a call to `_M_default_append` is not the result of the vector having to increase size because of an insertion, but the result of the vector having to increase size because of a call to `resize()`. (An insertion would trigger `_M_realloc_insert` instead.) So no mystery as to why it's called -- you call `resize()`. That brings us back to: *make sure that default constructing an element is not overly expensive.* It might be better to `reserve` than `resize` if the logic can handle that.